# How to get "Comand Line" property of a Process in powershell

Tags: powershell

I wonder how I can get the "the command line" property of a process shown in the Task Manager . I  mean, if  I run the following

```
Get-Process -Name "Firefox" | ? {$_.TotalProcessorTime -ne $Null} | Select-Object -Property Name, Id, Path
```

I get :

```
Name       Id Path                                         
----       -- ----                                         
firefox   728 C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe   
firefox  2260 C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe  
firefox  2612 C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe    
firefox  3992 C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

But I dont need the "Path" property  but **Command Line** instead , I mean for example:

```
Name   Id    **Command Line**                                                             
----   --  ----                                                                      
firefox 728 **"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -contentproc --chanel="1306.3.14958**                               
firefox 2260 **"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -contentproc --chanel="1306.4.9583**                               
firefox 2612 **"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -contentproc --chanel="1306.5.1392**                                
firefox 3992 **"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -contentproc --chanel="1306.6.21397**
```

And later on filter ( do a grep) of a part of a string found the command line column ( for e.g:1306.5.1392)   I know I can use findstr -i "1306.5.1392"  , but not sure if it`s the smartest way

Many thanks in advance  for your help!

Kind regards

Comment: You would need to use `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_process` in Windows PowerShell, however in [newer versions of PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), `Get-Process` objects have the `CommandLine` property (great excuse to download it ;))

Answer (score 3):

Query instances of [the `Win32_Process` WMI class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) to get the command line:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'" |Where-Object { 
    (Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime -ne $null 
} |Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

If you want to include the `TotalProcessorTime` value in the output, use `Select-Object` *before* filtering:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'" |Select-Object Name,ProcessId,CommandLine,@{Name='TotalProcessorTime';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime}} |Where-Object { $_.TotalProcessorTime -eq $null }
```

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                                            
   ````     Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox'"     ````                            doesn' t show me nothing.   I am using  Powershell 4.0.1.1 version.

Comment: @lanz PowerShell 4.x is very old. Why don't just install the latest PowerShell Core 7.0?

Comment: in wmi, the name is firefox.exe

Comment: The answer given by you, really works, but I have a small problem not specified above;     With that commandlet   I cannot show the TotalProcessorTime by process as: ````Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'" |Where-Object { 
    (Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime -ne $null 
} |Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine`,

Comment: The answer given by you, really works, but I have a small problem not specified above by me ;     With that commandlet   I cannot show the TotalProcessorTime by process.  If I select that value it appears empty

Comment: @lanz I've update the answer to address that :)

Comment: This works:   Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'" |Select-Object @{Name='TotalProcessorTime';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime}},Name,ProcessId,CommandLine |Where-Object { $_.TotalProcessorTime -ne $null }                         Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The name is wmi includes the .exe, so firefox.exe. Or

```
get-ciminstance win32_process | ? name -eq firefox.exe | select commandline
```

Powershell 7's get-process also has the commandline property.  Just return the string with foreach-object.

```
get-process firefox | foreach commandline
```

Comment: Nice hint on Get-Process, exactly what I was looking for.